# Looping and a boolean array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random

I'm in my first Java programming class ever, and I am currently attempting to write up a user-made method that will loop through a boolean array, give me a random number, check if the array says the generated number is true or false, and then generate a different number if the array has an index of the generated number that states true (TL;DR: Find a random index in a boolean array, and rerun if the randomly-found number is true). My current dilemma is that if I use a do/while loop, the loop will never stop if all values of the array are true, and using a if/else will only rerun the number once. How do I fix this?
Edit: my code so far:

```
public static int getNextQuestion(boolean[] queue){
    int nextq = ((int)((11*Math.random())+1));
    if (queue [nextq]){
        int nextq = ((int)((11*Math.random())+1));
```

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: In what way do the random number and boolean array relate to each other?

Comment: I am trying to generate a number that corresponds to an index in the array that has a value of false. @SamTebbs33

Comment: public static void main( String[] args ){
public static int getNextQuestion(boolean[] queue){
 int nextq = ((int)((11*Math.random())+1));
 if (queue [nextq]){
  int nextq = ((int)((11*Math.random())+1));   @ericbn

Comment: Still don't get the problem. You want to generate random indexes, check if they are true and if one of them is true, then finish. Right?

Comment: No, if it is true, I want to reroll. If false, then return it. @SergaRUS

Comment: Well, you need to define what your method *should* do in case ell the elements are true. Loop infinitely, or throw an exception, or... We can't decide what you want your code to do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you'll want to check your queue for all trues before calling your `getNextQuestion()`.  Then I would just use recursion until you generate a false.  You can keep track of how many time you call your recursive method to see that it's working...

```
static Random rand = new Random();
static int recursiveCount = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean[] queue = new boolean[] { true, false, true, true, false, true };
    if (checkIfAllTrue(queue) == false) {
        getNextQuestion(queue);
    }

    System.out.println("Recursive Count: " + recursiveCount);
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

public static void getNextQuestion(boolean[] queue) {
    recursiveCount++;

    int nextQ = rand.nextInt(queue.length);
    if (queue[nextQ]) {
        getNextQuestion(queue);
    }
}

public static boolean checkIfAllTrue(boolean[] queue) {
    // Check your queue for all trues before proceeding
    boolean allTrue = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        if (queue[i] == false) {
            allTrue = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return allTrue;
}
```

Results:

[image]

### UPDATE

After seeing the comments about returning the index of the random false index, I've updated `main()` and `getNextQuestion()`.  Everything else remained the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean[] queue = new boolean[]{true, false, true, true, false, true};
    if (checkIfAllTrue(queue) == false) {
        System.out.println("False index: " + getNextQuestion(queue));
    }

    System.out.println("Recursive Count: " + recursiveCount);
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

public static int getNextQuestion(boolean[] queue) {
    recursiveCount++;

    int nextQ = rand.nextInt(queue.length);
    if (queue[nextQ]) {
      return getNextQuestion(queue);
    } else {
        return nextQ;
    }  
}
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Basic answer

As stated by @Shar1er80, you need to check if all elements are true **before** iterating through your array. Here's a solution using a loop (iterative, not recursive) and `Math.random()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[] { true, false, true, true, false, true };
    int iterationNumber = 0;
    int nextItem;

    if (checkIfAllTrue(array) == false) {
        boolean retry;
        do {
            nextItem = generateRandomInt(array.length);
            retry = array[nextItem];
            iterationNumber++;
        } while (retry == true);

        System.out.println("The false is found at index " + nextItem);
    }

    System.out.println("iterationNumber = " + iterationNumber);
}

/**
 * Checks if all the elements of the given boolean array are true.
 * @param queue The boolean array to check.
 * @return True if all elements are true, false if at least an element is false.
 */
public static boolean checkIfAllTrue(boolean[] queue) {
    // Check your queue for all trues before proceeding
    boolean allTrue = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        if (queue[i] == false) {
            allTrue = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return allTrue;
}

/**
 * Generates an int between 0 included and range excluded.
 * @param range The maximum value of the range (excluded from generation).
 * @return An integer between 0 included and range excluded.
 */
public static int generateRandomInt(int range) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * range);
}
```

## Code improvements

Given it's your first Java course, the code above is verbose. The two first methods can be simplified, to take in account that

```
boolean b;
// Code that initiates b
if (b == true) {
    // Code here...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
boolean b;
// Code that initiates b
if (b) {
    // Code here...
}
```

And that you can iterate through an array with foreach loop (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html).

So you can have something more pleasant to read (the last method remains unchanged) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[] { true, false, true, true, false, true };
    int iterationNumber = 0;
    int nextItem;

    if (!checkIfAllTrue(array)) {
        boolean retry;
        do {
            nextItem = generateRandomInt(array.length);
            retry = array[nextItem];
            iterationNumber++;
            System.out.println("nextItem = " + nextItem);
            System.out.println("retry = " + retry);
            System.out.println("iterationNumber = " + iterationNumber);
        } while (retry);

        System.out.println("The false is found at index " + nextItem);
    }

    System.out.println("iterationNumber = " + iterationNumber);
}

public static boolean checkIfAllTrue(boolean[] queue) {
    // Check your queue for all trues before proceeding
    boolean allTrue = true;
    for (boolean element : queue) {
        if (!element) {
            allTrue = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return allTrue;
}
```